# Threads not running concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I hope this is not a repeat question, but I have looked at all the answers in other questions and none have satisfied my problem.

I have a program that has solves the Dining Philosopher's problem, and when I run the program, the threads wait until the next one is done before running another. This causes the thread's output to look like:

```
Philosopher 1 is EATING.
Philosopher 1 is THINKING.
Philosopher 5 is EATING.
Philosopher 5 is THINKING.
Philosopher 3 is EATING.
Philosopher 3 is THINKING.
```

... and so on. The expected output doesn't have an order. The threads should run concurrently. Here is my code, all of it is in here, with the interface just specifying the size of DINERS (5) and the State._______ is an enumeration with 3 states: State.HUNGRY, State.THINKING, and State.EATING.

```
import java.lang.Runnable;                                                      
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;                                            
import java.util.Random;                                                        
import java.lang.Thread;                                                        
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;                                           
/**                                                                             
 * This class handles the Philosophers, I hope they are hungry.                 
 *                                       
 * @version 4-20-15                                                             
 */                                                                             
public class Diner implements Runnable, PhilosopherInterface {                  

/** The lock used to control Thread access */                               
private final ReentrantLock lock;                                           
/** The state that the Philosopher is in (ex: Eating, Thinking etc.) */     
private State current;                                                      
/** The random number used to generate time sleeping */                     
private Random timeGenerator;                                               
/** The maximum time a thread can sleep */                                  
private final int maxTimeToSleep = 5000;                                    
/** The minimum time a thread can sleep (1ms) */                            
private final int minTimeToSleep = 1;                                       
private int philNum;                                                        
private int philIndex;                                                      
private Condition[] condition;                                              
private State[] states;                                                     

public Diner(ReentrantLock lock, int philNumber, Condition[] condition, State[] states)

    philNum = philNumber;                                                   
    philIndex = philNum - 1;                                                
    current = states[philNumber-1];                                         
    timeGenerator = new Random();                                           
    this.lock = lock;                                                       
    this.condition = condition;                                             
    this.condition[philIndex] = lock.newCondition();                        
    this.states = states;                                                   
    states[philIndex] = State.THINKING;                                     


}                                                                           

@Override                                                                   
public void takeChopsticks() {                                              

    states[philIndex] = State.HUNGRY;                                       
    lock.lock();                                                            
    try{                                                                    
        int left = philIndex-1;                                             
        int right = philIndex+1;                                            
        if(philNum == DINERS) right = 0;                                    
        if(philNum == 1) left = DINERS - 1;
test(left, philIndex, right);                                       
        if(states[philIndex] != State.EATING) {                             
            condition[philIndex].await();                                   
        }                                                                   
    }catch(InterruptedException e){}                                        

}                                                                           

@Override                                                                   
public void replaceChopsticks() {                                           
    try{                                                                    
    states[philIndex] = State.THINKING;                                     
    int left = philIndex-1;                                                 
    int right = philIndex+1;                                                
    if(philNum == DINERS) right = 0;                                        
    if(philNum == 1) left = DINERS - 1;                                     
    int leftOfLeft = left-1;                                                
    int rightOfRight = right+1;                                             
    if(left == 0) leftOfLeft = DINERS-1;                                    
    test(leftOfLeft, left, philIndex);                                      
    if(right == DINERS-1) rightOfRight = 0;                                 
    test(philIndex, right, rightOfRight);                                   
    }finally{ lock.unlock(); }                                              
    //states[philIndex] = State.THINKING;                                   
    //condition[left].signal();                                             
    //condition[right].signal();                                            
}                                                                           



public void think() {
System.out.println("Philosopher " + philNum + " is " + State.THINKING + ".");
    int timeToSleep = timeGenerator.nextInt(maxTimeToSleep) + minTimeToSleep;
    try {                                                                   
        Thread.sleep(500);                                                  
    }catch(InterruptedException e) {}                                       
}                                                                           

public void eat() {                                                         

        System.out.println("Philosopher " + philNum + " is " + State.EATING + ".");
    int timeToSleep = timeGenerator.nextInt(maxTimeToSleep) + minTimeToSleep;
    try {                                                                   
        Thread.sleep(500);                                                  
    }catch(InterruptedException e){}                                        
}                                                                           

@Override                                                                   
public void run() {                                                         

    while(true) {                                                           

        think();                                                            
        takeChopsticks();                                                   
        eat();                                                              
        replaceChopsticks();                                                
    }                                                                       
}                                                                           

public State getState() {                                                   
    return current;                                                         
}                                                                           

private void test(int left, int current, int right) {                       
    if(states[left] != State.EATING && states[current] == State.HUNGRY      
             && states[right] != State.EATING) {                            
        states[current] = State.EATING;                                     
        condition[current].signal();                                        
    }                                                                       
}                                                                           
}
```

Why are the treads not running concurrently? Thanks for the help!
EDIT: To run it, there is a driver that is this:

```
public class Lunch {                                                            

public static void main(String[] args) {                                    

    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();                               
    Thread[] diners = new Thread[PhilosopherInterface.DINERS];              
    Condition[] table = new Condition[PhilosopherInterface.DINERS];         
    State[] states = new State[PhilosopherInterface.DINERS];                
    for(int i=0; i<PhilosopherInterface.DINERS; i++) {                      
        states[i] = State.THINKING;                                         
    }                                                                       


    for(int i=0; i<PhilosopherInterface.DINERS; i++) {                      
        Diner diner = new Diner(lock, i+1, table, states);                  
        diners[i] = new Thread(diner);                                      
        diners[i].start();                                                  

    }                                                                       



}                                                                           

}
```

EDIT2: Figured out the problem, Answer below.

Comment: I edited the Original Post with the driver.

Comment: Must be another bunch of philosophers than the ones I know or they changed their dining habits.... The ones I know compete over spoon and fork and try to sequentially acquire both resources in order to eat, which can result in a deadlock when one holds the mutex representing a fork and the other holds the mutex representing a spoon, each trying to acquire the respective other.

Comment: Your `think()` and `eat()` methods each calculate a `timeToSleep`, but then don't use it.  They both always sleep for half a second.  Was that intentional?

Comment: How can you tell they're not running concurrently?

Answer (score 3):

Telling your threads to wait is not forcing them to work concurrently. If a thread needs to follow several steps before another one activates, then these methods(steps) should be synchronized.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using Synchronized? I would rather use Java Condition Variables than to use that.

Comment: I wish I could elaborate further on your question but my knowledge is not infinite. A question for you, why don't you want to use synchronized? Edit: and use java condition variables instead?

Comment: @user2751164 there is just no way to not use synchronized, or some other form of synchronization (barriers or latches) if your thread must execute in a certain order __and__ concurrently. Conditional statements are for single threaded flow.

Answer (score 0):

I only locked once at the beginning of takeChopsticks() and unlocked at the end of replaceChopsticks(), forcing the thread to do everything before unlocking.

I used the lock() and unlock() methods at the start and finish of both takeChopsticks() and replaceChopsticks(), allowing it to run concurrently.

Answer (score -1):

Try using an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Use `ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)`
and `ExecutorService.shutdown()` which will wait until all the `Runnable`s have terminated and shutdown the `ExecutorService`.